# Custom textview background not resizing correctly

Tags: ios, resize, textview

I'm having some trouble setting a custom background for my textviews. As I understand it, I can use a png image file and make it resize according to the size of my textview, with something like this:

```
UIImage *bubble = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue-bubble.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 6, 6, 12)];

UITextView *textIn = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 30)];
textIn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bubble];
```

What happens is that the image is not being resized properly, even after trying to change the parameters of the UIEdgeInsetsMake method.

I'm not sure as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't use the `colorWithPatternImage` method for resizing images, which caused the problem. I fixed the problem by creating separate imgviews for each textview and positioning the imgviews behind the textviews.

Hopefully this helps someone out there.